# Getting the data from the listview in the form of Map then how can i add particular row data into the database?

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, android-sqlite

I made a listview using the simple Adapter.i am getting the row data in the form of key and value(HashMap).i want to insert the particular row into the database but my problem is when i getting the row data it is coming in the form of key and value when the item is more then 1 then how can i add the data in the next row of the database.if anyone have any idea then please tell me.

This is the method()by which i am setting the simple adapter to the listview and iterate the each item from the map :-

```
private void showList(List<LineItem> list) {

    saleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (LineItem line : list) {
        saleList.add(line.toMap());
    }

    SimpleAdapter sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            saleList,
            R.layout.listview_lineitem,
            new String[]{"name", "quantity", "price"},
            new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.quantity, R.id.price});

    saleListView.setAdapter(sAdap);

    for (Map<String, String> map : saleList) {

        Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();

            Log.e("key..::>>", "" + pair.getKey());
            Log.e("value..::>>", "" + pair.getValue());.
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Model class :-

```
public class LineItem {

    private final Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private int id;
    private double unitPriceAtSale;

    public static final int UNDEFINED = -1;

    public LineItem(Product product, int quantity) {
        this(UNDEFINED, product, quantity, product.getUnitPrice());
    }

    public LineItem(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public LineItem(int id, Product product, int quantity,
                    double unitPriceAtSale) {
        this.id = id;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.unitPriceAtSale = unitPriceAtSale;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void addQuantity(int amount) {
        this.quantity += amount;
    }

    public double getTotalPriceAtSale() {
        return unitPriceAtSale * quantity;
    }

    public Map<String, String> toMap() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("name", product.getName());
        map.put("quantity", quantity + "");
        map.put("price", getTotalPriceAtSale() + "");
        return map;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUnitPriceAtSale(double unitPriceAtSale) {
        this.unitPriceAtSale = unitPriceAtSale;
    }

    public Double getPriceAtSale() {
        return unitPriceAtSale;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == null)
            return false;
        if (!(object instanceof LineItem))
            return false;
        LineItem lineItem = (LineItem) object;
        return lineItem.getId() == this.getId();
    }
}
```

I am getting the name,price and quantity correctly.I want to add name,price,quantity in the database.but the problem is i am getting the name,price,quantity in the form of key and value(Map).when i am thinking to add these things in database but how can i insert the data into database when i have multiple row data in the listview and getting the data from the listview in the form of key and value.because i want to insert the data in the database in the multiple rows (Example like listview row data i want to add data in the database).

My logcat is :-

```
 10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: quantity
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: 1
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: price
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: 200.0
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: name
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: aman
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: quantity
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: 2
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: price
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: 5556.0
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/key..::>>: name
    10-19 16:56:59.824 18890-18890/com.refresh.pos E/value..::>>: cghg

i want to add item in database like :-
three fields :- quantity   price     name
                  1        200.0     aman
                  2        5556.0    cghg
I hope anyone understand now what i want to do.
```

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to save name, price, quantity in to database. Is is correct?

Comment: @Mohammad Z  Yes ! but when i am getting the data from the hash map then i am getting in the form of key and value.then how can i savedata in the database in the muliple rows.please see my logcat. i updated it. i hope you will understand.

Comment: I think you have the multiple values in the hashmap object correct? like name="xxx",price=8999,quantity=900,name="yyy",price=6779,quantity=700

Comment: @KonaSuresh yes ! you got the point ! please tell me the solution. i updated my code.you see my logcat. you will understand what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the "saleList " having the map objects. So each map object is one row.

```
   ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
   for (Map<String, String> map : saleList) {

        Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();

       if(pair.getKey().equals("name")){
          cv.put(pair.getKey(),pair.getKey());

       }else if(pair.getKey().equals("price")){
       cv.put(pair.getKey(),pair.getKey());
       }else{
          cv.put(pair.getKey(),pair.getKey());


        }
        //here insert your contentvalues to db


        }
    }
```

I felt that each map having the only three values like name,price,quantity.

> If it is not correct, then you should create model class for each row
>   with those variables and insert the model class object into
>   ArrayList. then you can easily get the data as row.

Comment: this is not working ! and if i am creating the model class with those variables then how can i add data in those variables ??